# Inserting one entity into another one

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I don't even know how to title this one:

Lets say I have a manufacturer entity and a model entity, with a one-to-many relationship.
Each manufacturer can have multiple models (just using these as an example).

manufacturer has a tableview and its independent fetchedResultsController, then when you press on a manufacturer cell you go to models viewcontroller that also has its own tableview and fetchedResultsController, ofc showing the relevant added models.

Let's say I would like to take one of the models and copy them or cut them into another manufacturer, I was thinking of a method styled like:

```
-(void)copyThis:(Model*)model toThat:(Manufacturer*)manufacturer
```

I am grabbing the right manufacturer object and the right model object but how can I implement the insertion of one to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy

```
Model *newModel = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Model" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
newModel.property = model.property; //For every property
model.relationShipName = manufacturer;
[self.context insertObject:copyModel];
```

To cut

```
model.relationShipName = manufacturer;
```

(I assume that you have an xcdatamodeld and have generated an NSManagedObjectSubclass of your Model and Manufacturer entities)

Comment: I don't believe `NSManagedObject` conforms to `NSCopying` so `[model copy]` may not work.  If it did, then you would want to set the `relationShipName` property on the `copyModel` instance instead of on the `model` instance.

Comment: I believe copy is an instance method on NSObject so every object can use the method. Correct me if I'm wrong though

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve with copying?  Do you want a 'new' model with the exact parameters added to the other manufacturer, or do you want the relationship to be with the same model object?

Assuming you want to keep a single instance of the Model object:

```
Manufacturer *fromManufacturer = ...
Model *model = [[fromManufacturer models] objectAtIndex:...];
Manufacturer *toManufacturer = ...

[toManufacturer insertModelObject:model];

if (isCut) [fromManufacturer removeModelObject:model];
```

To get the `insertModelObject` and `removeModelObject` methods automatically, you can use Xcode to generate `NSManagedObject` subclasses for you automatically.  It's under the Editor menu when you're looking at the CoreData Model file.  Note that the names of the methods and objects may be different depending on the CoredData model structure and relationship names you've created.